# Crash while manually manipulating a UNICODE_STRING

Tags: memory-management, unicode-string

I get a very strange (for me) crash while manually manipulating a `UNICODE_STRING`:

```c
UNICODE_STRING ustrName;
UNICODE_STRING ustrPortName;
UNICODE_STRING linkName;
UCHAR m_COMPortName[6];

RtlInitUnicodeString(&ustrName, L"PortName");
status = WdfStringCreate(NULL, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &strPortName);
if(NT_SUCCESS(status)) // String created
{   status = WdfRegistryQueryString (hKey, &ustrName, strPortName); // strPortName is now "COM8"
    if (NT_SUCCESS (status)) {
        WdfStringGetUnicodeString(strPortName, &ustrPortName);
        m_COMPortName[0] = (UCHAR)ustrPortName.Buffer[0];
        m_COMPortName[1] = (UCHAR)ustrPortName.Buffer[1];
        m_COMPortName[2] = (UCHAR)ustrPortName.Buffer[2];
        m_COMPortName[3] = (UCHAR)ustrPortName.Buffer[3];
        m_COMPortName[4] = (UCHAR)ustrPortName.Buffer[4];
        m_COMPortName[5] = 0; // Force a null-termination
    }

}
WdfRegistryClose(hKey);

RtlInitUnicodeString(&linkName, L"\\??\\COM123"); // Init with lets say COM123, Breakpoint here...
linkName.Buffer[7] = (USHORT)m_COMPortName[3]; // First digit in the COM-port number // ** THIS LINE CRASH **
linkName.Buffer[8] = (USHORT)m_COMPortName[4]; // Second digit in the COM-port number // (if any else NULL)
linkName.Buffer[9] = (USHORT)m_COMPortName[5]; // Third digit in the COM-port number // (if any else NULL)
```

Disassembly:

```asm
902de533 6840072e90      push    offset mydriver! ?? ::FNODOBFM::'string' (902e0740) ** Breakpoint here (same as above...) **
902de538 8d45f8          lea     eax,[ebp-8]
902de53b 50              push    eax
902de53c ff1528202e90    call    dword ptr [mydriver!_imp__RtlInitUnicodeString (902e2028)]
902de542 660fb60d23392e90 movzx   cx,byte ptr [mydriver!m_COMPortName+0x3 (902e3923)] ** Start of the crashing line **
902de54a 8b55fc          mov     edx,dword ptr [ebp-4] ** Seems ok **
902de54d 66894a0e        mov     word ptr [edx+0Eh],cx    ds:0023:902e074e=0031 ** CRASH!!! **
902de551 660fb60524392e90 movzx   ax,byte ptr [mydriver!m_COMPortName+0x4 (902e3924)]
902de559 8b4dfc          mov     ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4]
902de55c 66894110        mov     word ptr [ecx+10h],ax
902de560 660fb61525392e90 movzx   dx,byte ptr [mydriver!m_COMPortName+0x5 (902e3925)]
902de568 8b45fc          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]
902de56b 66895012        mov     word ptr [eax+12h],dx
```

Both `linkName` and `m_COMPortName` looks correct in the Watch. Whats up?

Another solution is to in some way concatenate the unicode string `L"\\??\\"` with the dynamically read unicode string `L"COMx"`. But I don't know how to do that. I'm aware of `MultiByteToWideChar` but I'm not so fond of using it since it needs `windows.h` and when I include that file into my tiny KMDF-driver project the compiler gives me tons of errors...

All code made for Windows Vista in WinDDK 7600.16385.1 (KMDF)

Comment: Found this RtlUnicodeStringCat(&linkName, &ustrPortName) in #include <ntstrsafe.h>, still crashing...

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `RtlUnicodeStringInit`:

> Sets the Buffer member of the UNICODE_STRING structure to the
>   **address** that the source parameter specifies.

`linkName` buffer points to a constant (`L"\\??\\COM123"`) so it crashed when you try to modify it.